# PHP - can a method return a pointer?

Tags: php, pointers

I have a method in a class trying to return a pointer:

```
<?php
public function prepare( $query ) {
    // bla bla bla

    return &$this->statement;
}
?>
```

But it produces the following error:

**Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected '&' in **/home/realst34/public_html/s98_fw/classes/sql.php** on line **246**

This code, however, works:

```
<?php
public function prepare( $query ) {
    // bla bla bla

    $statement = &$this->statement;
    return $statement;
}
?>
```

Is this just the nature of PHP or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: He uses "public" so it's 5. And PHP 4 is dead dead dead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PHP doesn't have pointers. PHP has reference. A reference in PHP is a true alias. But you don'tneed them. Objects are passed by handle (so they feel like references) for other data PHP uses a copy-on-write mechanism so there is no memory/performance penalty. The performance penalty comes when using references as they disable  copy-on-write and therefore all the optimizations in the engine.

If you really want to return a reference youhave todeclare it in the signature:

```
public function &prepare( $query ) {
   // bla bla bla

   return $this->statement;
}
```

But as said: If $this->statement is an object there is no need.

See also http://php.net/references

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely have to look into the difference of pointers/references/aliases etc. I'll just return the object (it is an object).